# Drupal: Access Denied Error for downloading all uploaded files

Tags: drupal, access-denied

I had a site working just fine with Drupal 6.16. Then I updated to 6.17 (and updated all of the modules), and all of a sudden the uploaded files were all generating Access Denied errors.

If I switch the file system to Public, it all works fine (what I did as a workaround).

I tried a file compare to see what changed between editions and also searched all of the modules for possible places that the access denied function is called. I even changed file.inc to ignore other modules file_download methods temporarily with no luck.

There's no special access control modules installed.

Does anyone have any other ideas where to look to see where this could be bugged?

Everything else works fine. Just the "uploaded files" that get Drupal's Access Denied error.

I didn't change the settings.php or the .htaccess file.

Comment: Did you override/change/alter/... the .htaccess file?

Comment: Perhaps there was a mass file ownership change? Run `ls -l` and see who owns the drupal directories.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using wamp with php 5.3...
drupal 6.13 is not compatible with php 5.3

you should go to the wamp tray -> php -> version -> Get more...
you fly to the wampserver site : download php 5.2.11
install php 5.2.11 (the installer will find where to install it)
go again to the wamp tray -> php -> version
select php 5.2.11
then wamp tray -> restart all services

Now you can install drupal 6.13 without nay (?) trouble.

Note that drupal 7 will be compatible with php 5.3

Have fun :)

Comment: Not on WAMP. Installing works fine. Everything else works fine. Just the "uploaded files" that get Drupal's Access Denied error.